# Highcharts / Typescript: How to use scatter3d rotation?

Tags: typescript, highcharts

So I have `import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'` and my highcharts `chart: any` **inside a .ts file**, *not* a .js file.

The chart is a **scatter3d** (3dimensional). I want to make it rotatable. In JavaScript, it works by using

```
(function(H) {
  function dragStart(eStart) {
    eStart = chart.pointer.normalize(eStart);

    var posX = eStart.chartX,
      posY = eStart.chartY,
      alpha = chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha,
      beta = chart.options.chart.options3d.beta,
      sensitivity = 5, // lower is more sensitive
      handlers = [];

    function drag(e) {
      // Get e.chartX and e.chartY
      e = chart.pointer.normalize(e);

      chart.update({
        chart: {
          options3d: {
            alpha: alpha + (e.chartY - posY) / sensitivity,
            beta: beta + (posX - e.chartX) / sensitivity
          }
        }
      }, undefined, undefined, false);
    }

    function unbindAll() {
      handlers.forEach(function(unbind) {
        if (unbind) {
          unbind();
        }
      });
      handlers.length = 0;
    }

    handlers.push(H.addEvent(document, 'mousemove', drag));
    handlers.push(H.addEvent(document, 'touchmove', drag));


    handlers.push(H.addEvent(document, 'mouseup', unbindAll));
    handlers.push(H.addEvent(document, 'touchend', unbindAll));
  }
  H.addEvent(chart.container, 'mousedown', dragStart);
  H.addEvent(chart.container, 'touchstart', dragStart);
}(Highcharts));
```

like shown in an official demo here:
[jsfiddle scatter3d demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/)

but this doesn´t work in typescript. How can I rewrite this to make a scatter3d chart rotatable?

Answer (score 1):

You have to load and initialize `highcharts-3d` module like that:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts/highcharts";
import * as Highcharts3d from "highcharts/highcharts-3d";

Highcharts3d(Highcharts);
```

To make it rotatable just add this functionality after the chart is loaded using for example chart callback.

Check the demo posted below with an example of Angular app where `highcharts-angular` (official Highcharts wrapper) is used. It can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Demo (reload the view when the chart is rendered incorrectly - codesandbox issue):

- https://codesandbox.io/s/jp9jm5n6vy